Why does “var” in Java 11 bypass the “protected” access restriction?
Today, while working on a project for a college “Design Patterns” course (Java 11 required), I discovered a problem with the access restriction of the access modifier that can be bypassed by declaring var. I know how var is used, it's just a syntactic sugar that leaves the type inference to the compiler.
I can't figure out what type of alias the var is actually here:

is it "Child.InnerChild"? Wouldn't that be a type mismatch?
"InnerParent"? Doesn't this bypass the protected access restrictor?

Here is my simplified code:
public abstract class Parent {
    protected abstract static class InnerParent {
        public InnerParent self() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public static class InnerChild extends InnerParent {}
}

import anotherpackage.Child;

/**
 * Compiling with Java 11:
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // As we expected a compilation error: The returned static type does not match the expected type
        // Child.InnerChild innerChild = new Child.InnerChild().self();

        // As we expected a compilation error: Parent.InnerParent is package visible (protected)
        // Parent.InnerParent innerChild = new Child.InnerChild().self();

        // Why does it compile and run correctly here?
        // var is just syntactic sugar for the compiler type, it should be a Parent.InnerParent alias here,
        // why is var allowed to transgress the protected access restriction?
        var innerChild = new Child.InnerChild().self(); // perhce' non da' errore ? var e' un alias di cosa ?
        System.out.println(innerChild);
        System.out.println(innerChild.getClass().getName());
    }
}

I've also asked ChatGPT, but it's not responding as well as I'd like, and I'm not sure it's correct:

Why var Works

Inferred Type: The inferred type for var innerChild is Parent.InnerParent.
Access Rules: Since the type is inferred and not explicitly written in the code, the compiler doesn't enforce access restrictions for the declared variable.


I found a new problem: why can't I access getClass()?

However it is possible to compile this way.
System.out.println(((Object) innerChild).getClass().getName());
// OUTPUT: com.github.lorenzoyang.anotherpackage.Child$InnerChild


You're not going to access var innerChild anyway.

please do not emphasize (almost) everything - it makes reading difficult - the purpose of emphasizing is to mark a part as special, if everything is marked, it is not special any more

@user85421Sorry, I have modified the question.

@MartinZeitler Can you provide a more detailed answer?

thanks. BTW, Eclipse does not compile, error at innerChild on last line: "The type Parent.InnerParent is not visible" (probably same reason why VSC (I assume) is indicating error at getClass())

@user85421 I didn't realize that this code wouldn't compile through Eclipse, I'm using the latest version of Intellij IDEA, so it's possible that this is an Intellij IDEA issue?

I don't think so... I suspect, like Eclipse, IDEA will also create an executable that will throw a "unresolved compilation error" Exception or similar if run - what happens if that code is executed?  (BTW ((Object)innerChild).getClass()... should compile)

( BTW2 - var is a bit speacial anyway. For example you will be able to access members of an anonymous class like in: var test = new Object() {    private int it() { return 42; }    }; System.out.println(test.it()); -- will not work with Object test = new Object() { ... } )

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

sorry, not going to chat... and if you think that your var is not going to be a special type like the anonymous class, then I can't add anything

In NetBeans the line var innerChild = new Child.InnerChild().self(); not compile...

The answer is: var can represent anything the compiler can reason about as a type, even non-denotable ones: It lets you kick the can down the road. The error you ended up with has existed since before the introduction of var which proves this isn't a problem with var specifically; it's an intended (but somewhat odd) effect that matches the java lang spec.
Let's get into the specifics and break it down. But first:
Reminder – GPT is useless
GPT is a tool that produces an authoritative answer. As in, it'll pretty much keep trying to answer your question until something rolls out that looks authoritative. It can be a complete load of hogwash and in this case, indeed it is. Generally asking GPT for objective answers is a really bad idea: Sure, for simple questions it seems magically amazing, but then - it was a simple question. There are many ways to get the answer to a simple question. It's not what you should optimize for - that would be answers to complex questions. And GPT is very bad at that. In the sense that you can't tell. It'll give you a great sounding answer.
Remember this: Asking a GPT about language esoterica questions is ridiculous. Don't ever do it.
I'm not going to address the GPT answers any further. They are useless (possibly wrong, possibly not wrong. Any hint it gives might be relevant, or not. Hence, useless).
Non-denotable types
It's a language/compiler question so we refer to the source, the JLS:
JLS21 §14.4.1:

If the LocalVariableType is var, then let T be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context, and were thus a standalone expression (§15.2). The type of the local variable is the upward projection of T with respect to all synthetic type variables mentioned by T (§4.10.5).

And also note this clarification from the example box:

Note that some variables declared with var cannot be declared with an explicit type, because the type of the variable is not denotable.

That last part is implicit in the actual definition (in that the definition does not at any point state that the type that the compiler infers for var has to be denotable, you must therefore infer that it does not have to be; the note in the example box calls this out).
And it's key to understanding what's going on here. Here's an example of undenotable type use that's easier to follow than what this question has found:
class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new Object() {
      void test() {
        System.out.println("HELLO!");
      }
    };
    o.test(); // compiler error.

    var p = new Object() {
      void test() {
        System.out.println("HELLO!");
      }
    };

    p.test(); // works!!
  }

  void asAReminder() {
    new Object() {
      void test() {
        System.out.println("This has always worked"); 
      }
    }.test();
  }
}

Paste the above into a file, compile it - error on the line that says 'compiler error'. Remark it out, compile again, run it - works fine.
Which is bizarre in the sense that there is nothing you could possibly replace var with that makes this work. What's happening is that p's type is inferred to be the type of the anonymous local class and that type does have a test() method. This has always been part of java (well, since 1.2 or so, decades ago at this point), it's just that var now lets you declare local variables with that type. The asAReminder() method shows this; that code 'works' (compiles, and runs as you'd expect) in any java version of the past 2 decades.
Hence, var can denote InnerParent just fine here. It's not 'denotable' - if you literally replace var in your example with InnerParent it would fail to compile because InnerParent isn't accessible, but var merely represents the type of the expression the way the compiler treats it. And the compiler has to support it. After all, this is perfectly legal:
Object o = new Child.InnerChild().self();

The compiler is going to have to deal with the fact that the expression being assigned to o here is InnerParent (the def of self() says so, after all), and will therefore have to figure out in context that this is just fine.
We can prove that too!
Proof that this has nothing to do with var
Try to replace your main definition with the following:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child.InnerChild().self().getClass();
    }
}

That code will fail to compile, with the exact same error:

Object.getClass() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface


In other words, in java 8 (which doesn't support var at all - var as a feature was added in java 10) we can have the same concept: An expression which is, itself, legal, and whose type isn't accessible in the context we wrote it. It 'works' but the type is extremely poisonous: If you 'touch' it, almost anything you care to do to it will be a compiler error; even invoking final methods inherited directly from the obviously accessible java.lang.Object. Pretty much the only thing you can do with them is treat them as an accessible type first (by casting or assigning to a variable) or pass them to another method verbatim.
var merely lets you kick the can down the road.

var innerChild = new Child.InnerChild().self(); simply doesn't violate anything that the Java Language Specification says.
In Section 6.6, it is said that access control is applied when you use a qualified name.

Qualified names are a means of access to members of packages, classes, interfaces, type parameters, and reference types. When the name of such a member is classified from its context (§6.5.1) as a qualified type name (denoting a member of a package, class, interface, or type parameter) or a qualified expression name (denoting a member of a reference type), access control is applied.

You did not use the name of InnerParent here, so access control rules are not applied.
Some types of expressions also enforce access control. For example, a method call on a primary expression needs to make sure that the method being called is accessible. This is why calling innerChild.getClass() produces an error. Specifically, this clause prohibits access:

A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a class, interface, type parameter, or reference type, or a constructor of a class, is accessible only if (i) the class, interface, type parameter, or reference type is accessible, and (ii) the member or constructor is declared to permit access: [...]

InnerParent is not accessible, so its method getClass is also not accessible.
See the small print just before the header of section 6.6.1 for more info.

var is not a simple syntactic sugar that just gets replaced/rewritten with the name of the type of the expression on the RHS. The expression on the RHS might not even have a name (e.g. anonymous classes), or might not have a type (e.g. lambda expressions and method references). The type of a var variable is specified in 14.4.1

If the LocalVariableType is var, then let T be the type of the initializer expression when treated as if it did not appear in an assignment context, and were thus a standalone expression (§15.2). The type of the local variable is the upward projection of T with respect to all synthetic type variables mentioned by T (§4.10.5).

By writing var, you really are not using the name of InnerParent.
